# Custom shape size in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to add your own shape size in Jetpack Compose using Kotlin extensions?

Default Shapes class implementation in Jetpack Compose:

```
val Shapes = Shapes(
   small = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
   medium = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
   large = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp)
)
```

This is how I tried to add a new shape size:

```
val Shapes.ExtraLarge: CornerBasedShape
get() = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
```

But I am getting the *Receiver parameter is never used* warning and cannot use the new size in my Composables. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: yes definitely , you can check my article https://medium.com/@thegoldycopythat/custom-shapes-in-jetpack-compose-deep-dive-b987a52c743c

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `@get` for top level composable extension functions.

```
@get:Composable
val Shapes.ExtraLarge : CornerBasedShape
    get() = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
```

But if you see yourself doing this several times, then it's an indication that you need to start defining a custom design system where you can define properties such as colors and shapes that have logical meaning to your business/organization.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes/custom

Answer (score 1):

We have done this with our colors multiple times, but it's possible to extend the **Shapes**, **Colors** or **Typography** all the same way.

```
val Shapes = Shapes(
        small = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
        medium = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        large = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)
).apply {
    test = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
}

var Shapes.test: CornerBasedShape
```

It's very easy and possible without any annotation.

The first step is to create an extension field for the class.
After that you can use the **apply** method to extend the constructor call with your own value.

The new shape can be called simply like any other shape like this

```
MaterialTheme.shapes.test
```